# JRuby Error on Windows 7

Tags: jruby

I installed JRuby on my machine (Windows 7). Afterward when I check the version of JRuby to confirm whether JRuby is installed correctly or not, I get following error message

> c:\jruby-1.6.7.2\bin>jruby -v
>
> Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME:
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_15

Why am I getting this message?

Comment: Hi Harshal would you like to do freelancing in Jruby project?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this is due to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6696 (inability to work with 64-bits jdk)